# Libv8 error when deploying a rails app to a Ubuntu 10.04 VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, deployment, vps

I've installed nodejs and my app's Gemfile doesn't have any reference to therubyracer nor libv8.
This error keeps popping up:

`The Ruby Racer requires libv8 ~> 3.11.8...`

Any help is much appreciated!

My Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    Ascii85 (1.0.2)
    actionmailer (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
    activesupport (3.2.12)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    afm (0.2.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    better_errors (0.6.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.9)
    capistrano (2.14.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capybara (2.0.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 1.0.0)
    carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    celluloid (0.12.4)
      facter (>= 1.6.12)
      timers (>= 1.0.0)
    childprocess (0.3.8)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chosen-rails (0.9.11.2)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      sass-rails (>= 3.2)
    coderay (1.0.8)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    connection_pool (1.0.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.9.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger (1.3.1)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.1.1)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.1.8)
    debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (>= 1.1.1)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.8)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    facter (1.6.17)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.8.5)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    ffi (1.4.0)
    hashery (2.1.0)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    highline (1.6.15)
    hike (1.2.1)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-datatables-rails (1.11.2)
      jquery-rails
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, = 0.14, = 3.1.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    jwt (0.1.5)
      multi_json (>= 1.0)
    kgio (2.8.0)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.21)
    mini_magick (3.5.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    net-scp (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.6.5)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    oauth2 (0.8.0)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.1.3)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      rack
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
      omniauth-oauth2
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    paper_trail (2.7.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    pdf-reader (1.3.1)
      Ascii85 (~> 1.0.0)
      afm (~> 0.2.0)
      hashery (~> 2.0)
      ruby-rc4
      ttfunk
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    prawn (0.12.0)
      pdf-reader (>= 0.9.0)
      ttfunk (~> 1.0.2)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activerecord (= 3.2.12)
      activeresource (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.12)
    railties (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6,  1.4)
    redis (3.0.2)
    redis-namespace (1.2.1)
      redis (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-core (2.12.2)
    rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
    rspec-rails (2.12.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.12.0)
    ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    sidekiq (2.7.2)
      celluloid (~> 0.12.0)
      connection_pool (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1)
      redis (~> 3)
      redis-namespace
    simple_form (2.0.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    subexec (0.2.2)
    thin (1.5.0)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    ttfunk (1.0.3)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.6.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt-ruby
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  cancan
  capistrano
  capybara
  carrierwave
  chosen-rails
  coffee-rails
  database_cleaner
  debugger
  factory_girl_rails
  jquery-datatables-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mini_magick
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  paper_trail
  pg
  prawn
  rails
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  sidekiq
  simple_form
  thin
  uglifier
  unicorn
```

Comment: and your Gemfile.lock ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: I ran these commands on my VPS and everything worked. Thanks!